# Autosave the textbox control value in the web page without using webservice and settimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

Autosave the textbox control value in the web page without using webservice and settimeout function.Please Help me.Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onchage event handler of the TextBox and put the value to a hidden field in the page maybe.

But I really do not understand what you want to achieve.